# Gaussian mixture modelling (Mclust) in R on simple normal distribution fails

Tags: r, statistics, gaussian

I'm trying to understand Mclust so I thought the easiest way is to model a Gaussian with Gaussian mixture modelling. I would have expected G=1 as the best fit. However, I get G=6 and if I print them they do not even come close to the original Gaussian. Any hints what is wrong here?

```
x<-seq(-4,4,length=200)
y<-dnorm(x,mean=0, sd=1)
plot(x,y, type="l", lwd=2)
mod1<-Mclust(y)
ColourVec<-c('green','cyan','blue','red','yellow','yellow','yellow')
for (i in 1:max(mod1$G)){
  tmp<-mod1$classification==i  
  par(new=T)
  plot(density(mod1$data[tmp],adjust=2),col=ColourVec[i],xlim=c(-4,4),ylim=c(0,0.4))  
}
```

[image: Output image]

Cheers!
Durin

Comment: Haven't used `mclust` yet, but I think you want `rnorm(200,mean=0, sd=1)` instead of the call to `dnorm()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mclust(y,)` takes data, y, as input, eg. if you want data from a univariate normal, you need to simulate y by `rnorm()`. This leads to:

```
library(mclust)
x<-seq(-4,4,length=200)
y<-rnorm(200,mean=0, sd=1)
plot(x,dnorm(x,mean=0, sd=1), type="l", lwd=2)
mod1<-Mclust(y)
ColourVec<-c('green','cyan','blue','red','yellow','yellow','yellow')
for (i in 1:max(mod1$G)){
  tmp<-mod1$classification==i  
  lines(density(mod1$data[tmp],adjust=2),col=ColourVec[i])   
}
```

[image]

Increasing the number of simulations of course decreases your bias in the kernelsmoothed density.
Increasing to N=2000 simulations, 1000 from 2 different univariate gaussian with same sd, but different means leads to:

```
N<-2000
x<-seq(-4,7,length=200)
y<-c( rnorm(N/2,mean=0,sd=1), rnorm(N/2,mean=3,sd=1) )
plot(x,dnorm(x,mean=0, sd=1), type="l", lwd=2,xlim=c(-3,7))
lines(x,dnorm(x,mean=3, sd=1), lwd=2) 

mod1<-Mclust(y)
ColourVec<-c('green','cyan','blue','red','yellow','yellow','yellow')
for (i in 1:max(mod1$G)){
  tmp<-mod1$classification==i  
  lines(density(mod1$data[tmp],adjust=2),col=ColourVec[i])  
}
```

[image]